# Macbook Pro screen replacement doesn't display correctly

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, display

I've tried to replace the display on my MacBook Pro (ME294ll/a) Late 2013 but the image is not displayed correctly. It looks like this:

[image]

My brother had the same problem:

[image]

…but he just reconnected the ribbon cable and the screen began to work correctly. I tried several times to reconnect the ribbon cable, but to no avail.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well. If your MacBook Pro was purchased between February 2011 and December 2013, Apple determined that a small percentage these systems may exhibit distorted video, no video, or unexpected system restarts. Check out [this link](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) for the official Apple report.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you got a bad replacement display. It could be the cable, connector or another part. It could also be the GPU, or associated video hardware. But I would bet on the replacement screen being the culprit.

Comment: I tried to change the connector from crashed display – it didn't help. GPU is also ok because I use external monitor right now. Replacement screen also must be suitable (model: 661-8310). I've bought a brand new.